# FreeNAS - Imported old ZFS volume - but multiple datasets missing?

Tags: zfs, data-recovery

I have a FreeNAS server setup at my parents place. It was previously running FreeNAS Coral.

This had a single ZFS volume called 'datastore'. It's a RAIDZ-1 volume, comprised of 4 x Toshiba 5TB disks.

For some reason, that installation seems to have borked itself. Anyhow, I re-installed the boot USB with the latest FreeNAS 11 and booted up. I then went through the wizard to import my old ZFS volume.

It seemed to import the volume fine - the GUI also prompted me to update the ZFS pool version, which I did. However, I now notice that I seem to be missing several ZFS volumes - yet no errors are being reported.

Output of `zfs list`:

```
root@freenas:/mnt/datastore # zfs list
NAME                                                         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
datastore                                                   1.20T  9.01T   128K  /mnt/datastore
datastore/.system                                           8.81M  9.01T   140K  legacy
datastore/.system/configs-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da   128K  9.01T   128K  legacy
datastore/.system/cores                                      128K  9.01T   128K  legacy
datastore/.system/rrd-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da      7.90M  9.01T  7.90M  legacy
datastore/.system/samba4                                     279K  9.01T   279K  legacy
datastore/.system/syslog-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da    256K  9.01T   256K  legacy
datastore/ablage                                            1.20T  9.01T  1.20T  /mnt/datastore/ablage
freenas-boot                                                 743M  6.24G    64K  none
freenas-boot/ROOT                                            736M  6.24G    29K  none
freenas-boot/ROOT/Initial-Install                              1K  6.24G   734M  legacy
freenas-boot/ROOT/default                                    736M  6.24G   734M  legacy
freenas-boot/grub                                           6.29M  6.24G  6.29M  legacy
```

Output of `zpool status`:

```
root@freenas:/mnt/datastore # zpool status
  pool: datastore
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    datastore                                       ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/896b991d-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/88ace9fe-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/8957be15-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/8cbda7a2-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: freenas-boot
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    freenas-boot  ONLINE       0     0     0
      da0p2     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

And from the FreeNAS 11 GUI - volumes:

[image]

and disks:

[image]

There should be other volumes - e.g. "datastore/joo", or "datastore/photos" etc.

Any ideas of what's going on? Could the pool version somehow have borked something? =(.

The fact it reports 12 TB free is pretty worrying - but I am hoping the data is on the disks there somehow....any suggestions on getting to root cause, and/or recovering?

https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/imported-freenas-coral-zpool-into-freenas-11-multiple-volumes-missing.55072/#post-383534

Update - output of `zpool history -il <zpool>`:

```
% sudo zpool history -il datastore
Password:
History for 'datastore':
2016-11-13.18:41:21 [txg:5] create pool version 5000; software version 5000/5; uts freenas.local 10.3-STABLE 1003510 amd64 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:41:21 [txg:5] set datastore (21) compression=15 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:41:21 [txg:5] set datastore (21) aclmode=3 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:41:21 [txg:5] set datastore (21) mountpoint=/mnt/datastore [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:41:21 [txg:5] set datastore (21) aclinherit=3 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:41:24 <dispatcher> zpool create -o feature@embedded_data=enabled -o feature@filesystem_limits=enabled -o feature@enabled_txg=enabled -o feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump=enabled -o feature@extensible_dataset=enabled -o feature@large_blocks=enabled -o feature@empty_bpobj=enabled -o feature@bookmarks=enabled -o feature@hole_birth=enabled -o cachefile=/data/zfs/volume.cache -o autoexpand=on -o feature@lz4_compress=enabled -o failmode=continue -o feature@async_destroy=enabled -o feature@spacemap_histogram=enabled -O aclmode=passthrough -O mountpoint=/mnt/datastore -O aclinherit=passthrough -O compression=lz4 datastore raidz1 /dev/gptid/896b991d-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18 /dev/gptid/88ace9fe-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18 /dev/gptid/8957be15-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18 /dev/gptid/8cbda7a2-a974-11e6-b04f-a0b3cce4fa18 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:41:24 [txg:6] set datastore (21) org.freenas:permissions_type=PERM [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:41:29 <dispatcher> zfs set org.freenas:permissions_type=PERM datastore [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:45:45 [txg:59] set datastore (21) atime=0 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:45:50 <dispatcher> zfs set atime=off datastore [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:46:18 [txg:66] create datastore/ablage (42)  [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:46:18 [txg:67] set datastore/ablage (42) compression=15 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:46:18 [txg:67] set datastore/ablage (42) org.freenas:uuid=502dd243-a1aa-444d-9e98-435766fcf206 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:46:18 [txg:67] set datastore/ablage (42) aclmode=3 [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:46:18 [txg:67] set datastore/ablage (42) org.freenas:permissions_type=PERM [on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:46:23 ioctl create
    input:
        type: 2
        props:
            compression: 15
            org.freenas:uuid: '502dd243-a1aa-444d-9e98-435766fcf206'
            aclmode: 3
            org.freenas:permissions_type: 'PERM'
 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2016-11-13.18:46:23 <dispatcher> zfs mount datastore/ablage [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:25 [txg:20779] open pool version 5000; software version 5000/5; uts freenas.local 11.0-STABLE 1100512 amd64 [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 [txg:20781] import pool version 5000; software version 5000/5; uts freenas.local 11.0-STABLE 1100512 amd64 [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 zpool import -f -R /mnt 1196016705705258035 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 [txg:20783] inherit datastore (21) mountpoint=/ [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 [txg:20784] inherit datastore/ablage (42) mountpoint=/ [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 zfs inherit -r mountpoint datastore [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 zpool set cachefile=/data/zfs/zpool.cache datastore [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 [txg:20785] set datastore (21) aclmode=3 [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 zfs set aclmode=passthrough datastore [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:26 [txg:20786] set datastore (21) aclinherit=3 [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 zfs set aclinherit=passthrough datastore [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 [txg:20787] create datastore/.system (71)  [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 [txg:20788] set datastore/.system (71) mountpoint=legacy [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 ioctl create
    input:
        type: 2
        props:
            mountpoint: 'legacy'
 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy datastore/.system [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 [txg:20789] create datastore/.system/cores (77)  [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 [txg:20790] set datastore/.system/cores (77) mountpoint=legacy [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 ioctl create
    input:
        type: 2
        props:
            mountpoint: 'legacy'
 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy datastore/.system/cores [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 [txg:20791] create datastore/.system/samba4 (83)  [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 [txg:20792] set datastore/.system/samba4 (83) mountpoint=legacy [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 ioctl create
    input:
        type: 2
        props:
            mountpoint: 'legacy'
 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy datastore/.system/samba4 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:31 [txg:20793] create datastore/.system/syslog-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da (89)  [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 [txg:20794] set datastore/.system/syslog-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da (89) mountpoint=legacy [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 ioctl create
    input:
        type: 2
        props:
            mountpoint: 'legacy'
 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy datastore/.system/syslog-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 [txg:20795] create datastore/.system/rrd-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da (95)  [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 [txg:20796] set datastore/.system/rrd-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da (95) mountpoint=legacy [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 ioctl create
    input:
        type: 2
        props:
            mountpoint: 'legacy'
 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy datastore/.system/rrd-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 [txg:20797] create datastore/.system/configs-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da (101)  [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:32 [txg:20798] set datastore/.system/configs-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da (101) mountpoint=legacy [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:37 ioctl create
    input:
        type: 2
        props:
            mountpoint: 'legacy'
 [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:01:37 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy datastore/.system/configs-127b3ac88ebd45cc8152eb1d50a360da [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:12:04 [txg:20925] set feature@sha512=enabled [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:12:04 [txg:20926] set feature@skein=enabled [on freenas.local]
2017-06-04.17:12:09 zpool upgrade datastore [user 0 (root) on freenas.local]
```

Comment: It *shouldn't* be an issue, but you could try `zfs list datastore -t any -r` and see what comes out. I'd probably also want to image those disks immediately, in case you want to go back to an earlier txg, but it might be too late for that now.